# Clear tab color for specific selected sheets with vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, colors, tabs

I would like to delete sheet tab color for different sheets. E.g. only for sheets if their names containing "Defects".

Comment: Welcome to SO. And what you have tried until now?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Simples()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If InStr("Defects", ws.Name) > 0 Then
       ws.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```